# display the smallest value in while function in php

Tags: php

display the smallest value in while function in php?

this is my code

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lon = $_POST['lon'];

include 'koneksi.php';
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM node");
$col = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while($row = $query->fetch_object()){ 
      $rad = 0.0174532925;
      $r = 6371;
      $lat1 = $lat * $rad;
      $lon1 = $lon * $rad;
      $lat2 = $row->latitude * $rad;
      $lon2 = $row->longitude * $rad;

      $x = ($lon2 - $lon1) * (cos(($lat1 + $lat2) / 2));
      $y = ($lat2 - $lat1);
      $h = ((sqrt($x * $x + $y * $y) * $r));
      $hasil_jarak = number_format($h, 3, ".", ",");
      echo $hasil_jarak."<br>";
}
```

how can I display the smallest value from hasil_jarak?

I use the min () function just below echo, but the error, below is the error message.
the message: "When only one parameter is given, it must be an array".

how to fix it?

Comment: You can move your calculations directly into the SQL and ask your DBMS return min value too.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to keep track of the minimum value during the loop:

```
$minh = PHP_FLOAT_MAX;
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){ 
      $rad = 0.0174532925;
      $r = 6371;
      $lat1 = $lat * $rad;
      $lon1 = $lon * $rad;
      $lat2 = $row->latitude * $rad;
      $lon2 = $row->longitude * $rad;

      $x = ($lon2 - $lon1) * (cos(($lat1 + $lat2) / 2));
      $y = ($lat2 - $lat1);
      $h = ((sqrt($x * $x + $y * $y) * $r));
      if ($h < $minh) $minh = $h;
      $hasil_jarak = number_format($h, 3, ".", ",");
      echo $hasil_jarak."<br>";
} 
echo "minimum value is " . number_format($minh, 3, ".", ",");
```